# Where does the Selenium UI tests gets executed in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and the requirement is to trigger the aws pipeline which would further execute the tests. The selenium framework code would reside in AWS Lambda function , github repo would be integrated with aws pipeline and data is stored in S3 bucket.
I would like to know that assuming tests gets triggered then where in AWS the tests would get executed, does it provide some kind of browser within the aws services? (Like if we do testing in local system it would open the browser and execute the tests in browser).

Comment: AWS Lambda is a headless execution environment.  If you want to run something locally that shows a browser, it's something that's not Lambda.

Comment: Yes I mean I would want to know the options by which i can trigger selenium tests in AWS lambda like one of these you mentioned headless execution. Is there any other way also to execute the tests in AWS?

Comment: You could run Selenium in EC2, ECS, EKS, Workspaces, and probably other services.

Comment: Is it possible to run the tests on saucelabs via aws?